# How to find the place where a int conversion is failing in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column "`next` which is a string of numbers separated by ;

When I do

```
thedataframe.next.str.split(;).explode().astype(int)
```

It usually works but sometimes it fails with the error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

So I am debugging and the column is a column of 1135 rows.
I suspect in one of these rows there is an invalid value and this is causing the error

However it is 1135 values so how can I find where in the column it is failing?

I tried

```
>np.where(pd.isnull(thedataframe.next.str.split(';').explode()))
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: Can't you loop on the rows with `.iterrows` and print each row's index ?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could filter the data frame and search for non integers:

```py
df[~df["col"].str.contains(r'^\d+$', regex=True)]
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit what this is suppose to show me?

Comment: This will return all rows in the column `col` which are _not_ integer strings.

Comment: very strange. I tried it and when checking the col it says `'00000000000000020601233000121042;00000000000000020601233000121045'` which is valid...

Comment: Oh I found some contains `' '`